# Get installation date/time of an application installed from google play

Tags: android, datetime, google-play, installation-package

I have a requirement to get original installation date/time of an application installed from google play on the current device for a specific user.

I am able to get the last installation date from package manager but not the original installation date from google plays services.

Answer (score 2):

From API 9+:

```
long installed = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("package.name", 0).firstInstallTime;
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no method or API available to retrieve this information, sorry.

If it is  paid app, you could run your own server that makes an entry into a database whenever a purchase for this app takes place in your merchant account, and then retrieve the date and time from you server.

Comment: Thanks for replying, you mean to say i store installation date on my own server database table.